# How to properly pass collection for input in Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I need to pass a collection to the standard select input in Formtastic:

```
f.input :apple, :as => :select, :collection => Apple.all
```

The problem is, though that I need Formtastic to access a different method than name. Now this is really a problem. I can always pass the Array

```
f.input :apple, :as => :select, :collection => Apple.map { |a| a.format_name }
```

The problem is, that after this I will get strings in the controller instead of IDs which is not desired. I tried to pass Hash instead:

```
options = Hash.new
Apple.each { |a| Apple.store(a.format_name, a.id) }
f.input :apple, :as => :select, :collection => options
```

Now the problem is, that since I am using Ruby 1.8.7, the Hash order is unspecified and I of course need ordered input...

I can imagine some solutions, but all of those require unnecessary code.

Any idea how to solve this right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
f.input :apple, :as => :select, :collection => Apple.all, :label_method => :format_name, :value_method => :id
```

Comment: what about if we want not only :format_name, but smth like this:  :format_name + :another_name ?

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct indication in the formtastic documentation, but collection can be nested arrays as well, so problem is solved by:

```
f.input :apple, :as => :select, :collection => Apple.map { |a| [ a.format_name, a.id ] }
```

Comment: This did the trick for me as I happen to still be using a Ruby 1.8.7 version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way now:

```
f.input :apple,
        as: :select,
        collection: Apple.pluck(:format_name, :id)
```

This sets `collection` to an array of [name, id] tuples.  Easy!

**Soon-to-be deprecated way:**

Use the `member_label` option, e.g.

```
f.input :apple,
        as: :select,
        collection: Apple.all,
        member_label: :format_name
```

Documentation is [here in a code comment](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/822b04d08e9fa989ea8b65e9f2c61eb413b5eae8/lib/formtastic/inputs/select_input.rb#L36).